# How can I download and sort the videos based on topic wise while downloading from youtube_dl python script?

Tags: python, video, download, scripting, youtube-dl

When I download the playlists from udemy, all videos are saved into a single folder. My requirenment is I want to save them in different folders as per topic.
For that I used python script youtube-dl.

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: No, we can't. We can help you if you run into a specific problem. This is not a free code generator.

Comment: I made a script using Selenium to dowload MP3 song for all song in a youtube playlist. So the solution for me is use Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide an output template with the `-o` option, like this:

```
youtube-dl -o 'downloaded/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

followed by your playlist URL(s) and other options.

There is a **lot** of possible metadata that can be included in the filename, e.g. episode/track number, video resolution, description, autogenerated numbers, download protocol, artist, genre, release date and the like. Refer to [the documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) for the full list.

Note that not all websites and not all videos support all metadata properties. To see all the metadata available for one specific URL, use the `-J` option (pipe it through [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to format/select), for instance with:

```
youtube-dl -J PLwiyx1dc3P2JR9N8gQaQN_BCvlSlap7re | jq .
```